# python: is there a well-known function to normalize JSON representation of data?

Tags: python, json

Suppose, you've got a pair of variables: `request_data` and `response_data`.
They contain JSON/JSON-array data and you need to check, if those data are identical (i.e. the dicts/lists aren't the same, so they're not equal, but they contain identical data).

There's an obstacle for python JSON-like data comparison: Dicts with data may be equal, but due to the fact that they're unordered, they may have different representations, if we compare their `json.dumps`:

```
'[{
    "label": "JobName",
    "inputBinding": {"position": 1},
    "type": ["string"],
    "id": "displayName",
    "description": "SomeId to code sample"
}]'
    != 
'[{
    "id": "displayName",
    "label": "JobName",
    "description": "SomeId to code sample",
    "type": ["string"],
    "inputBinding": {"position": 1}
}]'
```

Is there a well-known function in some library to normalize representation of these data?

It should be recursive and account for nested dicts and lists.

Comment: Like `json.dumps(OrderedDict(sorted(data)))`, but recursive and recognizing dicts within lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare these objects you need to compare loaded dicts.

```
assert json.loads(s1) == json.loads(s2)
```

To ensure serializations are consistent with each other you may use [keyword argument `sort_keys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage).

> If sort_keys is `True` (default: `False`), then the output of dictionaries will be sorted by key.

```
assert json.dumps(d1, sort_keys=True) == json.dumps(d2, sort_keys=True)
```

If `d1 == d2`, equality above holds for any serializable data (including nested structures).

Answer (score 0):

Use json.loads to convert JSON to the Python objects and then compare.